# DB2: Using aggregate function sum() in one of the columns and I'm getting INTEGER OVERFLOW error

Tags: db2, overflow, aggregate-functions

In a DB2 database I'm trying to use the aggregate function `sum()` in one of the columns and I'm getting the "INTEGER OVERFLOW" error as the sum is very big. Could someone please let me know how to get the value . The column for which I'm calculating the sum contains file sizes in bytes. Any tricks to capture that sum without error?

Comment: What DB2 version and platform?

Comment: sum(cast(COLUMN_NAME as bigint)) resolved my issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, the `SUM()` function returns essentially the same data type as the one used for input. That is, if the input is `INTEGER` the output will also be `INTEGER` (or `BIGINT` on some platforms).

Cast the input to the data type that is available on your DB2 version and platform and that is capable of representing the sum of all values. For example:

```
select sum(decfloat(file_size_col)) from yourtable
```

Comment: Thanks Mustaccio... sum(cast(COLUMN_NAME as bigint)) resolved my issue.